# Error between SSL site and PayPal Standard

Tags: ssl, paypal

We have recently enabled SSL on our website and PayPal standard as an additional payment method to our ZenCart site.  However where the transaction appears to go through ok, no orders are being recorded and no notification emails are being sent out.  Also the auto return URL has lots of extra characters added.

I have checked settings and have added https:// for each URL back to my site

so IPN is https://mywebsite.com/ipn_main_handler.php
Auto return is https://mywebsite.com/index.php?main_page=checkout_process

My settings I take are as follows:

I have noted all my steps and hope this helps:

made a purchase with https://shaftdirect.com/sit-to-stand...est-p-152.html (its 1p)

click add to cart
click checkout
signed in :

(Shipping page)
Free delivery only option (already selected)
Special instructions: Added test ***********************Test**************************

(Payment Page)
Checked to agree to T&Cs
select paypal as payment

confirm
(sent over to paypal sign-in screen)
I log into my own account
click Pay now

It appears to work, but instead of the where I have the return url, https://shaftdirect.com/index.php?ma...eckout_process instead I am greeted with a blank screen and the following URL:

```
Code:

https://shaftdirect.com/index.php?main_page=checkout_process
&referer=paypal
&amt=0.01
&cc=GBP
&charset=windows-1252
&cm=zenid%3D5r70pquqt8gkltengfd3qkn5e6
&item_name=All%20the%20items%20in%20your%20shopping%20basket%20(see%20details%20in%20the%20store%20and%20on%20your%20store%20receipt).
&item_number=Shaft%20Direct%20Purchase
&st=Completed
&tx=0KW452399F310162G
```

And theres no record of the order or notification email sent out.

Please could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sorry, on this one occasion I spoke to my hosting team and there was an issue with dns resolvers resolving paypal.com from our servers.

They've done something their end and now it works fine.